# Drupal 8 ajax form load error, context.querySelectorAll is not a function

Tags: 8, ajax

I have created a custom module with ajax call, which are sending render form data that I receive in my ajax prototype in a js file like below.

```
Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.loadCommentFormCommand = function (ajax, response, status) {
    if ($('#comment-form-wrapper').length === 0) {
        $('.wall-posts').prepend(response.html);
          Drupal.attachBehaviors(response.html);
        }
      };
```

But it's showing me

```
context.querySelectorAll is not a function
```

Error. 
Does anyone face similar error or have some solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `Drupal.attachBehaviors` is an object representing a DOM element, `context`. You're currently providing it with a string.

In your case the correct code will probably be something like:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#comment-form-wrapper').get(0));
```

You don't pass data to behaviours through the `attachBehaviors` method, instead stash it somewhere in a global scope and pick it up later.

For example you might choose the `window`, `drupalSettings`, or some other object, depending on your general requirements and any other required uses of that HTML data.

Comment: Hi Clive, Thanks for your quick answer, Let me implement this and will come to you soon.